# Odd Chess Crown - How can it be fixed?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, transforms

I'm modeling a rook cheese piece but the crown seems off. It seems bent and not really, how can this be fixed?

NT: Zoom into the crown to see the fault.

[image]

Comment: you have overlapping faces and unconnected faces, the Subdivision Surface can't round the edges between faces that are not connected, you need to select all and press M > Merge by Distance with a Distance of 0.02, then create some bevels to sharpen the edges or bevel manually

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @moonboots, when you say select all do you mean just the crown or everything? And what do you mean bevels

Comment: Select the object, switch to Edit mode, select everything (A) and press M > Merge by Distance then in the Operator Box (bottom left of your 3D view) choose a Distance value of 0.02 in order to merge all the overlapping vertices

Comment: @moonboots thank you so much, it worked. I haven't used the bevel tool before that's why I was confused, however the Merge by distance worked.

Comment: Hello, @Newlearner23, I think the downvoting here may be because you have committed folks to a download of your file (for which, thanks,) before having an indication of whether they are likely to be able to help you. A screen-grab illustration showing your topology would have gone a long way, here.

Answer (score 1):

Select the object, switch to *Edit* mode, select everything (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* then in the *Operator Box* (bottom left of your 3D view) choose a *Distance* value of 0.02 in order to merge all the overlapping vertices.